# Access SQLite db from MMF

Tags: c#, sqlite, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I'm using `System.Data.SQLite` lib to access my SQLite database. I want to load the db file to memory and use MMF (Memory Mapped Files) to access the database.

Is this possible using the default [SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) library?

**edit:**

Alternatives on how I can have an in-memory database are welcome.

Comment: no... what you can do is: create an in-memory DB instance and load the contents from the DB file...

Comment: Can you provide the alternative as an answer please?

Comment: done... with 2 other options...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no...

You can:

- create an in-memory DB instance (specify in connection string `Data Source=:memory:`) and load the contents from the DB file into that instance... when you change contents of the in-memory instance your DB file won't get updated... you could later on save the in-memory instance content into a DB file... [one way to do this](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/2403.aspx)
- use a RAM disk and copy the db file into that RAM disk...
- modify the source code of the library to support MMF

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: [Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20130326111615/http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com:80/forums/t/2403.aspx) an archived snapshot of the page.